# Remove number in front of only one section without removing it from TOC

Tags: sectioning

I'm trying to remove the number in front of my Appendix section (and only this section not the other sections) but keep it in the TOC. Because when I use 
    section*{Appendix}
it is gone from the appendix and it also changes the number in front of the subsection to a chapter before this section (so for example, 8.1 becomes 7.1)

Comment: you can do `\bgroup
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{}
\makeatother
\section{Foo}
\egroup
\subsection{Bar}`

Answer (score 2):

Create something that would provide a useful syntax and that's easily changeable and consistent. Here's one example via `\insertappendix`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\insertappendix}{\par\stepcounter{section}%
  \section*{Appendix}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}

\section{Another section}
\subsection{A subsection}

\insertappendix
\subsection{A subsection}

\end{document}
```